# Math equations returning 0 when using variables between classes

Tags: java, class, math, subclass, parent

My final result when testing these classes returns zero/zero, but it should return an actual answer.
Here is a small sample of the code.

parent class:

http://pastebin.com/QvxqgrfN

subclass: (here lies the problem - by the way, the main section is for testing results. I will take it out afterwards.)

```
public class HW6Fraction extends Fraction {
   public HW6Fraction(int num, int denom) {
      super();
   }

   public Fraction add(Fraction f) { // Add method
      int num = getNumerator() + f.getNumerator();
      int denom = getDenominator() + f.getDenominator();
      Fraction result = new Fraction(num, denom);
      return result;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      HW6Fraction F1 = new HW6Fraction(4, 7);
      HW6Fraction F2 = new HW6Fraction(1, 3);

      Fraction F3 = F1.add(F2);
      System.out.println("sum=" + F3.getNumerator() + "/" + F3.getDenominator());
   }
}
```

Parent Class

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator; //Numerator of fraction
    private int denominator; //Denominator of fraction

    public Fraction(int num, int denom) { //Constructor
        numerator = num;
        denominator = denom;
    }

    public Fraction() { //Constructor w/ no parameters
        new Fraction(0, 1);
    }

    public Fraction(int num) { //Constructor w/ numerator parameter
        numerator = num;
        int denom = 1;
    }

    public int getNumerator() { //getNumerator method
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() { //getDenominator method
        return denominator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int num) { //setNumerator method
        numerator = num;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int denom) { //setDenominator method
        denominator = denom;
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction f) { //Add method
        int num = numerator * f.getDenominator() + f.getNumerator() *
                  denominator;
        int denom = denominator * f.getDenominator();
        Fraction result = new Fraction(num, denom);
        return result;
    }

     public Fraction subtract(Fraction f) { //Subtract method
        int num = numerator * f.getDenominator() - f.getNumerator() *
                  denominator;
        int denom = denominator * f.getDenominator();
        Fraction result = new Fraction(num, denom);
        return result;
    }

    public Fraction multiply(Fraction f) { //Multiply method
        int num = numerator * f.getNumerator();
        int denom = denominator * f.getDenominator();
        Fraction result = new Fraction(num, denom);
        return result;
    }

    public Fraction divide(Fraction f) { //Divide method
        int num = numerator * f.getDenominator();
        int denom = denominator * f.getNumerator();
        Fraction result = new Fraction(num, denom);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: the algorithm is wrong anyway, `1/2 + 1/2 != 2/4`

Comment: this was my instruction: "HW6Fraction class overrides the add() and subtract() of the Fraction class in such a way that the new 
add() method adds the two fraction objects’ numerators and denominators"

Comment: I've pasted the parent class as well as formatted your code for your HW6Fraction class. In future questions, we would appreciate it if you did this yourself. There's no sense in posting code that's poorly formatted and difficult to read, and then ask volunteers to put in effort to help you, if you haven't put in effort to make it easy for them to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing arguments to `super` constructor:

```
public HW6Fraction(int num, int denom){
    super();
}
```

should be:

```
public HW6Fraction(int num, int denom){
    super(num, denom);
}
```

otherwise the parent class won't initialize instance variables (they'll be `0` indeed).